# How can I open a html page on android phone from my local IIS Server?

Tags: android, html, iis, localhost, local

I want to display my html page on my android phone! My system is win7 and on my lochal IIS I created a new virtual directory but my android phone is not opening the html page just a html page!!! I tired http://192.168.1.4/TEST/mypage.html but cant open... I tired http://localhost/TEST/mypage.html but cant open... I there any way for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some possible problems:

Check your firewall settings as well as your anti-virus.

Also remember that some server software is case sensitive, so check the spelling.

Make sure the phone is connected to the same network as the server.

Make sure about the IP adress of the server, some routers use the 10.0.0.4 type adress

I hope this helps, these checks usualy work for me

Comment: thank you! I closed windows firewall and refresh page, it gave me an error acces denied.. and I allow from my page's folder to everyone.. Now it is ok.

Comment: +1 I'm working to a client server app with Android, exploiting a very simple personal server. Everything OK from the emulator, but no connection (and no any warning from windows) with my phone. It was windows firewall stealthy blocking my app. TY.

Answer (score 1):

Configure the firewall first and than publish the web site .